# Ghost Driver inside a Tomcat App

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium, phantomjs

I would like to use PhantomJS inside a Tomcat WebApp.

For this I found Ghost Driver which I successfully integrate to my app.
I added the dependency to Selenium: selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar

It works but there are some conflicts with the jar of Tomcat:

```
[exec] INFO: validateJarFile(/Users/charles/Pidoco/Editor/dev/webapps/rabbit/WEB-INF/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Why does it work when Tomcat say "jar not loaded"? Does Tomcat loaded a part of the jar?

Is it possible to get Ghost Driver working with Tomcat?

Comment: Can you explain why you would even want to do this?  I can't even begin to guess why you would do something so unusual.

Comment: I want to make screenshot of a website from my app.

Comment: Do you mean a screenshot of "another" website or a screenshot of itself?  You question is not very clear.   I assume you mean screenshot of itself because there are a million answers already on this site of how to use selenium to create screenshots of another site.

Comment: "I want to make screenshot of a website", it's clear that it's not only my website. Anyway I achieved what I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok.  I see you edited your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible by just adding some jars of Selenium and not the whole Standalone package.

Here the list of jar I needed:

```
commons-exec-1.1.jar
guava-18.0.jar
httpclient-4.3.2.jar
httpcore-4.3.1.jar
json-20080701.jar
phantomjsdriver-1.1.0.jar
selenium-api-2.42.2.jar
selenium-java-2.42.2.jar
selenium-remote-driver-2.42.2.jar
```

I mostly found them on http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: I'm not seeing how that would help anything.   Even if you could call code in one of those jars (from the server-side), it has no concept of the client side visual window-frame and will not be able to screenshot it.  Not even Sikuli API could do this, even if you loaded it client side.  A javascript-ish solution is the only possibility (if it existed) and the only alternative is a browser plugin of some kind, probably in combination with a online service.

Comment: With these JARs I'm able to call a URL and to take a screenshot. I found a very useful example here: https://github.com/maxbraun/phantomjs-wrapper

Comment: Of course you can, but per the question, try implementing that code within a website to take a screenshot of itself.  That's a no-go.